# Programmatically copy annotations from one PDF to another with Ruby

Tags: ruby, pdf

I have a large number of books in PDF format, mostly from publishers like the [Pragmatic Programmers](http://www.pragprog.com), and I have made many annotations (comments, highlights, notes, etc.) in the PDFs that I'd like to preserve.  This becomes a problem when the publisher updates the PDF and I download the update.  I'd like a way to merge my annotations (which are basically changes) with the new version.  Opening each one and manually copying and pasting is obviously a ridiculously tedious chore, so:

Is there any way to do this programmatically?  I'd prefer to use Ruby, but I'd be almost as happy with a shell script-based solution, and I'd even be willing to learn Python or use Perl if those were the only options.

Comment: Might this not be annotation program specific?

Comment: I would guess it has more to do with the PDF format specification.  Perhaps the annotations are not common from one annotation program to another, but they are still differences between the original and my modified copy, so I just want to merge my changes between A & B into C.

Comment: How would such a program work if the publisher added/removed pages or changed whole sections? Is that not a possibility?

Comment: The Comprehensive Perl Archive Network (CPAN) may provide what you need. For example, "Perl extension for appending annotations on PDFs" http://search.cpan.org/search?mode=all&query=CAM%3A%3APDF%3A%3AAnnot

Comment: @Jared: I don't know, mostly because I don't know the PDF spec.  In the best case scenario, the annotations are stored differently than other content (thus easily extracted) and they refer to the host content in a way still works if new paragraphs are added (say, by paragraph UUID).  So I just extract annotations and throw them in the new PDF.  It's probably much more difficult, though.

Comment: As much as I personally dislike Adobe as a company, their Acrobat Pro s/w (*not* the free version) will likely do what you want. It also has the capability to run scripted "batch sequences."